# How to make images zoomable with Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, zooming, ionic2

I've got a page with one single image, how can I make this image zoomable?

[My Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYHlk.png)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Image viewer for Ionic 2+

- Installation

> npm install --save ionic-img-viewer

- Add in app.module.ts

> ```
> import { IonicImageViewerModule } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     MyApp, 
>     HomePage
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
>     IonicImageViewerModule
>   ],
> ```

- Programmatic usage :

> < img src="IMAGE_URL" #myImage (click)="presentImage(myImage)" />
>
> ```
> import { ImageViewerController } from 'ionic-img-viewer';
>
> export class MyPage {
>   _imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController;
>
>   constructor(imageViewerCtrl: ImageViewerController) {
>     this._imageViewerCtrl = imageViewerCtrl;
>   }
>
>   presentImage(myImage) {
>     const imageViewer = this._imageViewerCtrl.create(myImage);
>     imageViewer.present(); 
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> DEMO : [Demo ionic-img-viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKI3o.gif)

Answer (score 1):

I found this workaround on the Ionic forum:

html:

```
<ion-scroll (pinch)="pinchEvent($event)" scrollX="true" scrollY="true" zoom="true" style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background':'url('+src+') no-repeat','width' : width + 'px', 'height' : height + 'px', 'transform' : 'rotate('+rotacion+'deg)', 'background-size' : 'contain', 'background-position' : 'center'}" style="margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;"></div>
</ion-scroll>
```

.ts methods:

```
pinchEvent(e) {
    this.width = this.pinchW * e.scale;
    this.height = this.pinchH * e.scale;

    if(this.timeout == null){
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.timeout = null;
            this.updateWidthHeightPinch();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.timeout = null;
            this.updateWidthHeightPinch();
        }, 1000);
    }
}

updateWidthHeightPinch() {
    this.pinchW = this.width;
    this.pinchH = this.height;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as a reference, this is the link to the issue and forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/zoom-on-image-in-ionic-2/45910/13

Answer (score 1):

I code "pinch" event myself - it was very simple (I use it to zoom building floor map):

```
div class="floor-map"
     style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; cursor: move;"
     (touchstart)="mapMoveStart($event)"
     (touchend)="mapMoveStop($event)"
     (touchmove)="mapMove($event)"
     tappable
     #floorMapRef
> 
    <img [style.width]="width + 'px'"
         [style.height]="height + 'px'" ...>
</div>
```

And in mapMove I have something like this:

```
pinchLenght = -1  // -1 means no pinch
...

mapMoveStart(event) {
    this.pinchLenght = -1; // "reset" pinch
    ...
}

mapMove(event) 
{
    if(event.touches.length==2) { // two fingers detection 
        let length = Math.abs(event.touches[0].clientX-event.touches[1].clientX)
              + Math.abs(event.touches[0].clientY-event.touches[1].clientY);

          if(this.pinchLenght < 0) { // case: first pinch "touch"
            this.pinchLenght = length
          } else {
            let delta = length - this.pinchLenght;
            this.pinchLenght = length;

            if(delta>0) {
              this.zoomMap(1.05);
            }
            if(delta<0) {
              this.zoomMap(0.95);
            }
         }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

And in method `zoomMap(zoomFactor: number)` I properly change `this.height` and `this.width` (which was 'bind' to `<img>` tag).

Comment: Is mapMoveStop() code missing?  ...or should the call be removed?

Comment: @elingerojo I only show 'idea' - my code was more complicated - I initialize and deinitialize some things in my code at start and end - if you also need to do it then fill mapMoveStart and create mapMoveStop